# RDLC Report expression (Grandtotal)

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I am trying to do calculation in RDLC report. But I not allowed to **Add Total** for **Excess** expression like what I do for **TotalQty**.  I cannot figure out what is the problem because same method I am able to apply at other columns

**TotalQty Grandtotal**

[image: TotalQty GrandTotal]

**Excess grandtotal**

[image: Excess grandtotal]

**Result:**

[image]

Please help and advise if any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never see that exists this option to add a total!

You can right click on *excess grand total cell*, choose *Expression* and enter a simple `Sum` of the expression used to calculate Excess.

i.e.: `=Sum(Fields!TotalQty.Value - Fields!PSQLevel.Value)`